# Animate a textblock from a point to another

Tags: animation, uwp, textblock

I want to move a TextBlock element from the rigth part of the screen to the left one (Like text at the news).

```xml
<Canvas>
    <!-- Offset the text using a TranslateTransform. -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Picker}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="33" >
         <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
              <TranslateTransform X="2" Y="2" />
         </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Picker}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="33" />
</Canvas>
```

I can't find a Property/Action to achieve that, I'm really newbie to UWP , and I know that the XAML I have, doesn't do anything like that. 
It only put another TextBlock like a shadow effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of possible solutions - by usage of some *VisualStates*:

```xml
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="InvBoolConverter"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="States">
            <VisualState x:Name="Left">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsOn, Converter={StaticResource InvBoolConverter}}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Right">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="200" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsOn}"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <!-- Offset the text using a TranslateTransform. -->
    <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="Test" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="33" />
    <ToggleSwitch  x:Name="myButton" Margin="0,50,0,0" OffContent="Left" OnContent="Right"/>
</Canvas>
```

and the converter in the behind:

```cs
public class InvertBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => !(bool)value;
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , It's exactly the effect I wanted.

Is there a way to loop throught the animation without the need of a button?

I set the Duration 0:0:0 to the Rigth one , so It look like the text is always comming from the Rigth to the left.

Is there a way to change the state once the Rigth one finish, to start the Left, and then the Rigth?

Something like thist:


   while(true){
    after Right do Left Animation
    afet Left do Rigth Animation
    }

Comment: @NahuelOvejero You mean AutoReverse property of animation?

Comment: not exactly, I don't want to do the animation in the inverse way, just start over with the TextBlock at the initial position, go to end of the canvas, and restart... like a loop , always restarting , but not going from left to rigth, only right to left

Comment: You're probably looking for the RepeatBehavior struct property, which you can define on your animations. If you want it to loop forever, set it to "Forever".

Comment: @NahuelOvejero Try what André B said. You can also find some more information [at MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/storyboarded-animations).

Answer (score 2):

I've create a Templated Control in one of my projects, where the text moves automatically when the Text is larger than the rectangle itself... maybe that will help you or gives you an idea

```
public enum MarqueeScrollingDirection
{
    FromLeft,
    FromRight,
    FromTop,
    FromBottom,
    None,
}

public sealed class MarqueeUserControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarqueeDirectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MarqueeDirection), typeof(MarqueeScrollingDirection), typeof(MarqueeUserControl),new PropertyMetadata(MarqueeScrollingDirection.None));
    public MarqueeScrollingDirection MarqueeDirection
    {
        get { return (MarqueeScrollingDirection)GetValue(MarqueeDirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MarqueeDirectionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarqueeTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MarqueeText), typeof(string), typeof(MarqueeUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
    public string MarqueeText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MarqueeTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MarqueeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public MarqueeUserControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MarqueeUserControl);
        this.SizeChanged += MarqueeUserControl_SizeChanged;
    }

    private Canvas ContentCanvas;
    private TextBlock MarqueeTextBlock;
    private Storyboard storyboard;
    private DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation;

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        MarqueeTextBlock = (TextBlock)GetTemplateChild(nameof(MarqueeTextBlock));
        ContentCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild(nameof(ContentCanvas));

        if (MarqueeDirection != MarqueeScrollingDirection.None)
        {
            MarqueeTextBlock.SizeChanged += MarqueeUserControl_SizeChanged;

            storyboard = new Storyboard();
            doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            doubleAnimation.AutoReverse = true;
            doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

            if (MarqueeDirection == MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromLeft || MarqueeDirection == MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromRight)
            {
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)");
            }
            if (MarqueeDirection == MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromTop || MarqueeDirection == MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromBottom)
            {
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doubleAnimation, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)");
            }

            Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, MarqueeTextBlock);
        }
        else
        {
            (MarqueeTextBlock.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X = (ContentCanvas.ActualWidth - MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth) / 2;
        }
    }

    private void MarqueeUserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MarqueeDirection != MarqueeScrollingDirection.None)
        {
            bool play = false;

            RectangleGeometry rectangleGeometry = new RectangleGeometry()
            {
                Rect = new Rect(0, 0, ContentCanvas.ActualWidth, ContentCanvas.ActualHeight)
            };
            ContentCanvas.Clip = rectangleGeometry;

            storyboard.Stop();
            storyboard.Children.Clear();

            switch (MarqueeDirection)
            {
                case MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromLeft:
                    doubleAnimation.From = MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth ? ContentCanvas.ActualWidth - MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth : 0;
                    doubleAnimation.To = 0;
                    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth ? ((MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth - ContentCanvas.ActualWidth) / 10) +1 : 0));

                    play = MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth;
                    break;
                case MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromRight:
                    doubleAnimation.From = 0;
                    doubleAnimation.To = MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth ? ContentCanvas.ActualWidth - MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth : 0;
                    doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth ? ((MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth - ContentCanvas.ActualWidth) / 10) + 1 : 0));

                    play = MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth;
                    break;
                case MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromTop:

                    play = MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth;
                    break;
                case MarqueeScrollingDirection.FromBottom:

                    play = MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth > ContentCanvas.ActualWidth;
                    break;
                case MarqueeScrollingDirection.None:

                    play = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (play)
            {
                storyboard.Children.Add(doubleAnimation);
                storyboard.Begin();
            }
            else
            {
                (MarqueeTextBlock.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X = (ContentCanvas.ActualWidth - MarqueeTextBlock.ActualWidth) / 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:uc="using:roomZone.UserControls">

<Style TargetType="uc:MarqueeUserControl" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="uc:MarqueeUserControl">
                <RelativePanel x:Name="RootElement"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                    <Canvas x:Name="ContentCanvas" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                            MinWidth="100" MinHeight="16" >
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MarqueeTextBlock"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding MarqueeText}"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                       FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                       FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"
                                       FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}"
                                       FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" >
                                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform />
                                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </Canvas>
                </RelativePanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```